# AWS Command Line Tools need recoding for secure login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

The AWS command line tools appear to be broken on both Linux (Ubuntu PP) and Windows (7).  In both cases, after setting up the login credentials correctly and trying to run the most basic tool (`getBalance.sh`), I get a failure to authenticate.

```
An error occurred while fetching your balance: This request must be made over a secure channel. You must use 'https' rather than 'http'.
```

Seems simple enough, but there's nothing in the manual nor in the installed directory which would suggest that this is an option supported by the command line tools.

Has someone already modified the shell scripts to use a secured connection?  If not, any clues as to where I should begin the modifications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't used the tools extensively so can't say this solution is extensively tested but getBalance.sh worked after doing this

See this thread:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=333485

From the link:

> Edit the Command Line Tools Installation Directory\bin\mturk.properties file and edit the service_url to use https instead of http – i.e. https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/?Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester for production, and https://mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com/?Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester for sandbox.

Comment: +1 for discussion and helpful link.  I don't understand if they publish all that info why they don't just change the CLT! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info. If you ever get around to it, could be useful to simply edit out the first bit for lazy/less savvy readers. Changing just the mturk.properties file in a regular text editor worked for me... no need to get down and dirty with grep and sed.